# Getting the x and y coordinates from cv2.contour in Open CV Python and store it to different variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour

I'm printing the contour from cv2.findContours. It prints out something like these: 
    [[370 269]]
What i want is to get the 370 and store it into a variable.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()


    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower = np.array([0,0,255]) 
    upper = np.array([255,255,255])

    imgThreshHigh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
    thresh = imgThreshHigh.copy()

    _,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh, 
                cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    print(contours)

    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('Object',thresh)
    k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?post your code...

Comment: I just edited the post.

Comment: @Luisito see if the answer suits your expectation.

Comment: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)"

Comment: @Luisito Are you doing it the right way? Because it doesn't for me

Answer (score 2):

Do you know destructuring ?

```
data = [370, 269]
x, y = data

print(x)
# 370

print(y)
#269
```

Or, if data is a list of list:

```
data = [[370, 269]]
[[x, y]] = data

print(x)
# 370

print(y)
#269
```

Comment: I got this error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)" when i did this:

x, y = contour

Comment: Edited. Destructuring works when you know the number of expected elements in your input data.

Comment: Still got the same error. Can you add it to my code, i just edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

This might be late for you, I guess it will help someone.
To get the x, y value of a contour I used this

```
for contour in contours:
    x, y, _, _ = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    print(x, " ", y)
```

This gets the x, y coordinates of the starting point of the contour.
The two underscores are width and height, ignored as we don't need them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I wrote to write the coordinates into a nested list. The list contains as many lists as contours. Each individual list hosts a list of XY coordinate of the contour.

```
def get_xy_list_from_contour(contours):
    full_dastaset = []
    for contour in contours:
        xy_list=[]
        for position in contour:
            [[x,y]] = position
            xy_list.append([x,y])
        full_dastaset.append(xy_list)
    return full_dastaset
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the following for storing all `x` and `y` coordinates for a single contour:

```
x = []
y = []
for k in contours:
    for i in k:
        for j in i:
            x.append(j[0])
            y.append(j[1])
```

I am sure there must be a faster way !!

Comment: The `x` and `y` coordinates of every contour is stored in separate lists

Comment: i think this is not what im looking for, but its true that it extract the x coordinates.

Comment: Is there a way to separate the top from the top part of the contour and left from the right using these values?

Answer (score 0):

```
kx = contours[k][:,0,0]
ky = contours[k][:,0,1]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.